# I cannot configure the site during installation

Tags: 8, installation

I have installed MAMP and Drupal 8 into my windows 10 machine.

I can successfully setup database and installed modules but while setting up site, i am getting below error.

> Call to a member function setRecipients() on null in standard_form_install_configure_submit() (line 25 of core\profiles\standard\standard.profile).
>   standard_form_install_configure_submit(Array, Object)

Comment: Hi Gunavant, Welcome to Drupal answers. Looks like other people got the same problem : check [this issue on drupal.org](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2780071) and try the patch at the end of the issue or other suggested solutions

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a known issue in Drupal core, tracked on drupal.org. Please follow the issue over there, try out the submitted patches and provide your findings back.